# Is there a gmail console client to run on Windows?

Tags: console, gmail

I found this package on Ruby h[ttp://sup.rubyforge.org/](http://sup.rubyforge.org/)

Wonder if there is something similar to run on Windows without all these Ruby packages.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. You can use Command line tools for the Google Data APIs( http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) There is also extensive documentation attached, of examples and best usages.
It supports Gmail, Picasa etc. and allows you to do most of the things thought console statements.

Comment: sounds good, but I dont see gmail commands here: http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/ExampleScripts

Comment: The Google command line API is apparently [broken](https://code.google.com/archive/p/googlecl/): `8 June 2015: GoogleCL is currently broken due to the OAuth1 turndown, and likely to remain so. Thanks for your support over the years, and apologies for the lack of prior notice.`

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding a command line IMAP client.  I did a quick Google search and got some hits but I don't have any experience using them.  I recommend you look into that.  Seeing as gmail supports IMAP and POP3, you probably don't need a specialized gmail client.

Just search for: Windows IMAP command line client